# Forwarding reference: returning T when given T&& and T& when given T&

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider a class `A`, how can I write a template having the same behaviour as

```
A& pretty(A& x)
{
    /* make x pretty */
    return x;
}

A pretty(A&& x)
{
    /* make x pretty */
    return x;
}
```

Knowing that I want to:

1. modify the argument (`x`) in the exact same way, independently of whether the parameter is an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference (in fact, the two sections `/* make x pretty */` are identical), hence having a single function;
2. avoid unnecessary copying;
3. be able to use the function to modify a variable;
4. be able to "pipeline" the function call, no matter if the argument is an rvalue or an lvalue.

As an example for 3. and 4., consider the following use case:

```
void read_A(const A& x) { /* ... */ }
void take_A(A&& x)      { /* ... */ }

A x();
read_A(pretty(x));
take_A(pretty(A()));
```

---

My idea was to take advantage of forwarding references while limiting the allowed parameters to references to `A`. But what about the return type?

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, A>::value>
/*???*/ pretty(T&& x)
{
    /* make x pretty */
    return x; //?
}
```

Comment: You want a template, so why is there a class `A` ?

Comment: Nothing here is a forwarding reference.

Comment: OP has idea with forwarding reference at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply write

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T somefunc(T&& a) {
  /* do something with a */
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  return std::forward<T>(a);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int a = 5;

  somefunc(a);
  somefunc(5);

  return 0;
}
```

which will return

```sh
T somefunc(T &&) [T = int &]
T somefunc(T &&) [T = int]
```

As you can see, the functions have the signature you want. In the first call, `T` gets `int &`, and hence, the return value of `int &`. In the second, you have `T = int = int &&`, which is again what you want.

**EDIT.** By the way, your initial thought of applying `std::is_same` for disabling overload resolution for types other than `A` seems to be wrong, too. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same),

> If `T` and `U` name the same type with the same const-volatile qualifications, provides the member constant value equal to `true`. Otherwise value is `false`.

Hence, you may want to use something like `decay`, or at least a combination of `remove_cv` and `remove_reference` to apply the logic you want. Below is the modified version of the above code, which now includes the overload resolution enabler.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> T somefunc(T &&a) {
  /* do something with a */
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  return std::forward<T>(a);
}

template <class T, typename std::enable_if<
                       std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, float>::value,
                       int>::type = 0>
T onlyfloat_correct(T &&a) {
  /* do something with a */
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  return std::forward<T>(a);
}

template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, float>::value, int>::type = 0>
T onlyfloat_wrong(T &&a) {
  /* do something with a */
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  return std::forward<T>(a);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a = 5;
  const float b = 5;

  somefunc(a);
  somefunc(5);

  onlyfloat_correct(b);
  // onlyfloat_wrong(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a template here at all.  You can take advantage of the fact that a rvalue reference is an lvalue all call `pretty` in the rvalue reference overload so you only have to code the `make x pretty` logic in the lvalue overload.  That looks like

```
A& pretty(A& x)
{
    /* make x pretty */
    return x;
}

A pretty(A&& x)
{
    return std::move(pretty(x));
}
```

Comment: You'd better move it afterwards.

Comment: @T.C. As in `return std::move(pretty(x));`?